# Python 3.6 with Selenium IDE 2.9.1 exported script line from selenium import selenium does not work

Tags: python, webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-rc, smartclient

I created some test cases in Selenium IDE 2.9.1 when I export the test case to Python Remote Control the script looks pretty good.  Because we are using SmartClient and have some js extensions in Selenium IDE I think RC is the only route I can go.

I have the Selenium server 3.3.1 and I can start and run that fine.

When I try to run the file from the console as in: python filename.py  I get the error ImportError: cannot import name 'selenium'

the beginning of the file looks like this: 
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re

When I do from python prompt:

> > from selenium import webdriver  (it works) 
> >     from selenium import selenium   ( get the above error)

What am I missing?  I installed selenium with pip and it works in some cases.

Seems like a versioning issue.  Does Selenium IDE 2.9.1 only produce scripts for certain version of Selenium server with Python remote?

Not sure whether I need the older RC server, and if so where would the files that it is looking for come from?

Color me confused and obviously a newbie to python, selenium etc.  Any help appreciated!!  Thanks!